# Continuing to eat in a place that is visible from the initial eating place

Tags: halacha, blessing, see-sight-vision-blind

The Shulchan Aruch Harav brings in Orach Chaim 178:1

> א) היה אוכל בחדר זה ונטל המאכל בידו והלך לחדר אחר לאכול צריך לחזור
>   ולברך שכיון שעמד והלך למקום אחר עמידתו זו היא גמר אכילתו וזו אכילה
>   אחרת היא וטעונה ברכה בתחלה  אע"פ שלא הסיח דעתו בינתיים ואפילו חוזר
>   למקומו לאכול צריך לחזור ולברך שכיון ששינה מקומו בינתיים הפסיק אכילתו
>   ....
>   **... ומכל מקום אם במקום שאוכל יכול לראות את מקומו הראשון שאכל שם אפילו דרך חלון ואפילו מקצת מקומו אין צריך לחזור ולברך אפילו מבית לחצר
>   ואפילו לא היה כן בדעתו כשבירך** ...

What this is saying is that if you eat something whose after blessing is Borei Nefashot - then if you leave the room/house and continue to eat in place #2 then this is considered an interruption, and if you want to continue eating (in place #2) what you started to eat (say) - you'll have to bless again.

[regarding room-to-room: prior intention helps, as apposed to house-to-house: intentions prior to the initial blessing to cover house #2 won't help]

However: when does the above apply? If you **can't see** from place #1 to place #2.

If you *can see* place #2 from place #1 - *even partially* - then going to place #2 is not considered an interruption and you could continue eating there without an additional blessing. (even without prior intentions to include place #2 in the initial blessing)

**My Question:**

According to Shulchan Aruch Harav, if I'm standing on a high place with a massive view: does this mean I could continue eating throughout the whole area of the view. Can this be compared to the case brought in Shulchan Aruch 'MiBayit LaChatzer'?

Comment: בכל הרואה​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​. Have you ever been to [Shiloh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shilo_(village))?